# Proxy request uses my home IP in beautifulSoup project

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, proxy

I have a script that works no issues, except the proxies do not work. I want it to use a new proxy from proxies.txt each time it starts the request.

```
proxy_list = []

for line in open('proxies.txt', 'r'):
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    proxy_list.append(line)

def get_proxy():
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    proxies = {
        "http": f'{str(proxy)}',
        "https": f'{str(proxy)}'
    }
    return proxies

# Opening URL file 
def loop():
    with open('urls.json','r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        url_list = data['urls']
    pos = 0
    while True:

        # Sleep for 3 seconds between each request 
        time.sleep(20)


        if pos >= len(url_list):
            pos = 0
        url = url_list[pos]
        pos += 1

        proxies = get_proxy()

        result = requests.get(url.strip() ,headers=header,timeout=6)
```

It seems to just use my home IP instead of the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.get('example.com',headers=headers,proxies={'https': proxy_url})
```

My suggestion is to add the proxy reference while you are opening the url.